# Dispatch software with inventory of products with variable prices

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Sorry in advance for the long of the post but i can't explain it in other way, considering that English is not my native language :S

I create it (With the help of the WWW) a software with php/mysql for the dispatch of products with inventory and the problem I have is that I don't know how to  calculate the cost of the dispatch when I have entries of the same product with different price.

My DB looks like this:

[image: BD]

- `Producto` table: only maintains id, name and quantity of the product of the inventory
- `Ingreso` table: it register the entry of the products with their respective prices at the moment of the purchase (Only table that register prices)
- `Devoprov` table: it register the return to the suppliers
- `Transacciones` table: it register the dispatch with an id, where is headed, id of the product, quantity of the product, comment, who made it, date y id_tra it register a 1 for dispatch and a 2 for return.

With PHP, I register this way the dispatch

```
  if(isset($_POST['btnnewsal'])){   

     //Array Productos
    require_once 'config.php';
    for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['itemNo']); $i++ ) {
    $idventa = $_POST['venta'];
    $idpro = $_POST['itemNo'][$i];
    $res = $_SESSION['nombre'];
    $cre = "NOW()";
    $comentario = $_POST['notes'];
    $centro = $_POST['cbocod'];
    $canpro = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
    $qryUpt = "INSERT INTO transacciones VALUES ('$idventa','$centro','$idpro','$canpro','$comentario','$res',$cre,1)";
    mysqli_query($con,$qryUpt) or die(mysqli_error());
    }

    //Disminuir inventario
    for ($i=0; $i < count($_POST['itemNo']); $i++ ) {
    $idpro = $_POST['itemNo'][$i];
    $canpro = $_POST['quantity'][$i];
    $qryUpt = "UPDATE producto SET uni_pro = uni_pro-'$canpro' WHERE id_pro='$idpro'";
    mysqli_query($con,$qryUpt) or die(mysqli_error());
    }

}
```

Mi form for getting the products it looks like this (despacho.php)

```
<form class="form" method="post" action="despacho.php">
        <div class="form-group">
               <label for="cbocod" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Centro Medico:</label>
              <div class="col-sm-6">
                <select class="form-control select2" id="cbocod" name="cbocod" style="width: 50%;">
                    <?php
                    $u->llenarcombocentros();
                     ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>
                </div>
        <div class="form-group">
               <label for="cbocod" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Codigo Transaccion:</label>
              <div class="col-md-1">
                <input type="text" style="text-align: center;" class="form-control" id="venta" name="venta" value="<?php $u->contarventas(); ?>" readonly>
                  </div>
                </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <table id="vender" width="90%" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="2%"><input id="check_all" class="formcontrol" type="checkbox"/></th>
                        <th width="15%">Codigo</th>
                        <th width="35%">Nombre</th> <!-- 34% -->
                        <th width="10%">Stock</th>
                        <th width="10%">Cantidad</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="case" type="checkbox"/></td>
                        <td><input type="text" data-type="id_pro" name="itemNo[]" id="itemNo_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt changesNo" autocomplete="off" required></td>
                        <td><input type="text" data-type="nom_pro" name="itemName[]" id="itemName_1" class="form-control autocomplete_txt changesNo" autocomplete="off" required></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="stock[]" id="stock_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="number" name="quantity[]" id="quantity_1" class="form-control changesNo" autocomplete="off" onkeypress="return IsNumeric(event);" ondrop="return false;" onpaste="return false;" required></td>





                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
            <button class="btn btn-danger delete" type="button">- Borrar</button>
            <button class="btn btn-success addmore" type="button">+ Agregar Producto</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <br><br>
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="notes" class="col-sm-1 control-label">Comentarios:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="notes" name="notes" placeholder="Comentarios">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Limpiar</button>
                <button type="submit" id="btnnewsal" name="btnnewsal" class="btn btn-info pull-right">Despachar</button>
        </div><!-- /.box-footer -->
    </div>
    </form>
```

and this form get his data with this js and it works with jqueryUI.autocomplete and ajax

auto.js

```
$(document).on('focus','.autocomplete_txt',function(){
type = $(this).data('type');

if(type =='id_pro' )autoTypeNo=0;
if(type =='nom_pro' )autoTypeNo=1;


$(this).autocomplete({
    source: function( request, response ) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'ajax.php',
            dataType: "json",
            method: 'post',
            data: {
               name_startsWith: request.term,
               type: type
            },
             success: function( data ) {
                 response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                    var code = item.split("|");
                    return {
                        label: code[autoTypeNo],
                        value: code[autoTypeNo],
                        data : item
                    }
                }));
            }
        });
    },
    autoFocus: true,            
    minLength: 0,
    select: function( event, ui ) {
        var names = ui.item.data.split("|");                        
        id_arr = $(this).attr('id');
        id = id_arr.split("_");
        $('#itemNo_'+id[1]).val(names[0]);
        $('#itemName_'+id[1]).val(names[1]);
        $('#stock_'+id[1]).val(names[2]);
        $('#quantity_'+id[1]).val(1);

        }               
}); });
```

and my ajax.php

```
<?php
require_once 'config.php';
if(!empty($_POST['type'])){
    $type = $_POST['type'];
    $name = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
    $query = "SELECT id_pro, nom_pro, uni_pro FROM producto where       UPPER($type) LIKE '".strtoupper($name)."%'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $data = array();
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $name = $row['id_pro'].'|'.$row['nom_pro'].'|'.$row['uni_pro'];
        array_push($data, $name);
    }   
    echo json_encode($data);exit;
}
```

and i came with this for the reports but it does not do what i need it only show the total of products that have been dispatched

```
require_once 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['generar'])){  
$start  = $_POST['desde'];
$end  = $_POST['hasta'];
$centro = $_POST['cbocod'];

if($centro==-1){
$qryMem = "SELECT calendar.datefield AS DATE, IFNULL(SUM(transacciones.can_ven),0) AS total_sales FROM transacciones RIGHT JOIN calendar ON (DATE(transacciones.cre_dep) = calendar.datefield) WHERE calendar.datefield BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end' AND transacciones.id_tra=1 GROUP BY DATE";
$memresult =  mysqli_query($con, $qryMem) or die(mysqli_error());
```

I hope you guys can help me to show the cost of the dispatch with the multiple prices that can have a same product because i been tryng for days and i really dont know how to do it. **I am willing to change the DB or anything to resolve this**

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com).

Comment: Possibly a more informative link on SQL Injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: thanks i'am gonna fixed that!, but no help with my question? =(